# Why am I getting null when I request the FileName?

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, file-upload, enctype

The following *HTML* snippet makes a *POST* request to a servlet `SendFileName`.

```
<form method="post" action="SendTheFileName" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div id="Files_to_be_shared"> 
                      <input type="file" id="File" name="FileTag" />
                      <input type="submit" value="Share" /> 
                </div>
</form>
```

In the servlet's *POST* method I try to get the file name by calling :

```
String FileName = request.getParameter("FileTag")
```

but I am getting `null`. Why is that ?

*I am using Apache commons for file upload. It is working fine. I don't know why do I get null when the enctype is multipart/form-data while using only the jdk.*

Comment: You have to parse the request using commons file upload or somthing like that.Try these links:http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/

Comment: @Renjith _have to_ means ? Why does it return `null` ?

Comment: I think the problem is b'coz of the enctype. It is _multipart/form-data_

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the file in correct location? Try to use `"\SendTheFileName"` and `.getParameter` returns null when the argument dosn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servlet 3.0 API (Java EE 6) provides methods to access the content of a multipart post:

See [HttpServletRequest.getParts()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts%28%29)
You should have one [`Part`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html) for the file and one for each parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, **all** the form parameters are transferred as multipart.

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List items = upload.parseRequest(request);

// Process the uploaded form items
Iterator iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

    if (item.isFormField()) {
       // ** here you get the non-file parameters **
    } else {
        processUploadedFile(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to get the file name using jdk ? The above method is using apache commons

Comment: No, when using multipart the browser sends everything as multipart : file (data + filename), parameters, ... Unless you write your own implementation of the RFC 1867, you have to use some library to extract each part. Java SE doesn't include one. Don't you already use Commons FileUpload ?

Comment: I am using.But i am looking to do this using jsk.Are you sure there isn't a way ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In case you're using a JEE6 compliant server I have added another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting `null` because when form is entype of "multipart/form-data" and your input type is "file" it won't go inside HttpServletRequest requestParameterMap().

You have to use another option from Java EE 6 like this:

```
Part filePart = request.getPart("FileTag"); // or "File" - I am not sure 
                                            // that not for id value 
                                            // you should search
String fileName = filePart.getName();
```

Also if you can use JSF not just Jave EE Servlets there (in JSF 2.2) are special tag for input type="file":

```
<h:inputFile value="#{myFileUploader.file}"/>
```

This should help.